# Understanding blinking LED of Hard disk SATA configured in Raid 5

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, raid5

on a **HP Proliant ML 350 G4p** are installed and configured 4 hard disk SATA in RAID 5 mode. Two of the four hard disk have green LED blinking irregullary, one off and another green LED ON without blinking.

I look for this behavior and I read on HP documentation this info ([HP link](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01726637&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=3884315&prodTypeId=15351#A3))

[Online/activity LED (green)] **On**
[Fault/UID LED (amber/blue)] **Off**
[Interpretation] **The drive is online, but it is not active currently.**

I think only two disks are working and then RAID 5 configuration is not complete or do not works well; what is meaning of **online** respect **active** in this case?

What do you think about?

2011 02 11 Update:

The operating system is a Windows 2003 server. I use Hp Storage Tool to manage the hard disk of the server.
 From HP storage tools I get these informations:
controller 1 (adaptec 2610SA)
Direct-attached devices
Port 0 - Optimal (232,89 Gb)
Port 1 - Optimal (232,89 Gb)
Port 2 - Hot Spare (232,89 Gb)
Port 3 - Optimal (232,89 Gb)

Logical drives (1):
disk - Optimal (465,66 GB)

Comment: I have restarted the server and, suddnely, the 3 LED of hard drive of the RAID are blinking normally. At this point I suppose a problem in Adaptec SATA RAID controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a configuration/management interface or CLI commands to configure and/or check the status of your RAID system, the arrays, logical volumes and the hard discs.

Could it be that the fourth disc is configured as a hot standby disc and that is the reason why it is off?

Which operating system are you running?

Can you access logical volumes on the RAID?